# Is there a way to prevent VSCode auto-formatting from adding a space between question marks and words

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-code, flowtype

VSCode auto-formatting keeps adding a space between question marks in my type specification of my React class.

I think it only started happening in the new version of VSCode March 2019 (version 1.33), but I may be wrong

I use a reactjs + flowtype stack in VSCode and the following change happens on format.

```or-tag-here
class IdPRPConfigC extends React.Component<{file: ?string}, {}> {}
```

Becomes

```or-tag-here
class IdPRPConfigC extends React.Component<{file: ? string}, {}> {
```

Note that a space was inserted after the optional flag (?).

Comment: Do you have other extensions, like babel or prettier, installed? They might be causing this. Or it might be the default formatter that is built into VSCode.

Comment: I think it's the default formatter, I don't have anything else installed for formatting. This occurs when I run "Format File" and it is using the VSCode default formatter.

Comment: I would recommend using either [ESLint](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) or [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) to format code with Flow types. VSCode knows how to handle TypeScript but Flow syntax seems to throw off the built-in formatter. Check both sites for documentation on how to support Flow.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the extension called "Auto Close Tag" and it was editing my configuration to put space between question marks.